# Disable a mat-button from a list of buttons in angular5

Tags: angular-material, angular5

Hi I am a newbie to angular. I am using a mat-table with 3 rows and 2 columns. I want to enable/disable a mat-button in a row when I click on the mat-input. I achieved the click event but, the attribute is getting assigned to all the buttons. I want it to be assigned to one button in a row. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code

html

```
<mat-table #user [dataSource]="activeDataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" [value]="user.email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" (click)="enableButton()">
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="save">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Edit</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
      <button mat-button [disabled]="disableButton" (click)="saveUser(user)" ng-disabled="true" color="primary" class="mat-raised-button mat-warn">
        Save
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

TS

```
disableButton: boolean = true;
 enableButton(){
this.disableButton = false;
```

}